# How to handle two step conversion in XML using R?

Tags: xml, r, markup

I am parsing one xml using R (XML package). XML has following markup.

```
 <  &lt;
 >  &gt;
 &  &amp;

Input Text: 
       My age is &amp;gt; 65 years years. 

       output: My age is gt;65 years.
```

Expected output: My age is >65 years.

```
  How to get 2-step(1) for converting &amp; into & (2)  &gt; into '>' ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function like this

```
batchgsub <- function(patternmatrix, string) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(patternmatrix)) {
        p = patternmatrix[i,1]
        r = patternmatrix[i,2]
        string <- gsub(p,r,string)
    }
    return(string)
}
```

and specify your patterns to be replaced like this

```
> pm
     [,1]    [,2]
[1,] "&amp;" "&" 
[2,] "&gt;"  ">"
```

Then you can "chain" the replacements as many times as you want.

```
> s <- "My age is &amp;gt; 65 years."
> batchgsub(pm, s)
[1] "My age is > 65 years."
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sub("&gt;" , ">", 
          sub("(&amp;)", "&", 
                "My age is &amp;gt; 65 years.") )
[1] "My age is > 65 years."
```

Comment: i need standard package to read this text and convert it automatically

Comment: I can appreciate that not everyone has English as a first language, but I do not understand what you are asking. This is code that depends on the 'base' package. You cannot get much more "standard" than that.